# Notepad++ Increase number of lines scrolled when user scrolls

Tags: notepad++, line

When I use my Notepad++ editor, and I scroll within the editor, the lines only move by 1. I have my computer settings set to 6 lines per scroll, but they are not translating in Notepad++. I also cannot find the setting within the preferences. It's not the end of the world, I just would like my scrolling experience to not change when swapping from the browser to Notepad++ ect.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's an optin in Npp. May be you'll have more chance at https://superuser.com/

Comment: I had similar problem. After changing mouse to new one, Notepad++ started scrolling only one line at a time, instead of my standard 3 lines. Problem disappeared after restarting Notepad++ (which suggests that it loads those settings when it opens).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it through the OS/system settings, but you need to **restart** notepad++ after that changes.

Tested on Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H1 (64-bit) with notepad++ v.7.5.6 (32-bit).

This answer is attributed to @Pshemo comment.

Answer (score 1):

For my MSI WS60, Win10Pro, go to Settings>Devices>Touchpad>in the touchpad sensitivity drop down box, set it to most sensitive, and yes, close and reopen Notepad ++. Worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Doesn't this change the sensitivity of the touchpad everywhere?